# How to find a element xpath without Content-desc, resource Id or text attributes

Tags: android, selenium, appium, appium-android

Using Appium,

I want to click on an (arrow) button in the below picture. But the button has no resource-id, content-desc or text. So, is there any method by which we can click on the button. I am using java language for writing scripts to run. Thank you in advance:)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find element `By.XPath`:

```
//*[@class='android.widget.Button'][1]
```

The above for first `android.widget.Button`.

If in the page there are `android.widget.Button` more than one, you can try to change sequence of `[1]`.

With *java*, you can collect them in list and create a condition to make sure there are button more than one or not:

```
List<MobileElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.Button']"));

MobileElement nextBtn;
MobileElement backBtn;
if(buttons.size()==1) {
    nextBtn = buttons.get(0);
}else {
    nextBtn = buttons.get(1);
    backBtn = buttons.get(0);
}

//if you want click
nextBtn.click();
```

**Note**:

Not sure how to you initialize the `driver`, also you can change `MobileElement` to `AndroidElement`

Comment: again thanks man :) It worked also I tried this one @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@class = 'android.widget.Button']" )
 it is also working, but I've a doubt after clicking next in the next page there are 2more button forward and backward. May I know how to click forward again using the same xpath instead of taking new one.

Comment: @saicharan Not sure I'm understand you mean. But if you want achieve for second button, you can try `@FindBy(xpath = "(//*[@class = 'android.widget.Button'])[2]" )`

Comment: On a page with two buttons you’d likely use an index of 2 for the forward button and an index of 1 for the back. You could make your code “smart” by detecting if there are one or two buttons and referencing them appropriately. 

That said, this is a very brittle solution.

Comment: @MikeCollins No other way else to do it, without unique attribute (or without Content-desc, resource Id, text attributes, etc). That's all that can be done (with index based on available attribute). Btw, answer updated with java code.

Comment: okay, got it. Thanks both of you #MikeCollins, @frianH for responding and also for updating the answer in java.

Comment: @frianH, I didn't want to assume what his application would look like with two buttons. Who knows? There may be a hidden button between the two!? Just covering my bases with the "likely." #thatQAmindset

Comment: @MikeCollins So, btw, what your better approach for this issue? :)

Comment: Hrm. I just have been confusing something. I'd have done it your way :) Edit: Oh, you added the code later.

Comment: I have one question, why not just put an identifier?